# Calculating the set field of associative cache

Tags: cpu-cache

In this example:

> Assume a system’s memory has 128M words. Blocks are 64 words in length
> and the cache consists of 32K blocks. Show the format for a main
> memory address assuming a 2-way set associative cache mapping scheme.
> Be sure to include the fields as well as their sizes.

The following is supposed to be the solution:

> Each address has 27 bits, and there are 7 in the tag field, 14 in the
> set field and 6 in the word field.

I understand how the word field was calculated (2^6 = 64), but I don't understand how is the set field 14?.

Shouldn't the answer be 8?

Block size is 64 words, to find the number of sets we divide total number of blocks **32K** by set size which is **64*2=128B** (multiply by 2 since it's 2-way), my calculation should be correct, am I missing something?

> 32KB/(64*2)B = 32KB/128B = 256 = 2^8
>
> (Which implies that we need 8 bits for the **set** field)

Comment: 32K is the number of blocks, not their size.

Comment: @AProgrammer Block size is 64 words, to find the number of sets we divide total number of blocks **32K** by set size which is **64*2=128B** (multiply by 2 since it's 2-way), my calculation should be correct, am I missing something?

Comment: There are 32K blocks of 64 B.  So there are 16K sets of 2 blocks.

Answer (score 3):

The memory has $128$M words = $2^{7+20}$ = $2^{27}$ words. Hence it needs needs $27$ bits for address space.

Each block has $64$ words, so the block offset = $2^6$ words. So Block offset field can be represented by $6$ bits.

Number of lines in the cache = $\frac{Cache Size}{Block Size}$ =Number of blocks = $32$K blocks = $2^{5+10}$ = $2^{15}$ blocks.

Number of sets in the cache = $\frac{Number of Lines}{Set Associativity}$ = $2^{15}$ blocks / $2$ blocks per set = $2^{14}$ sets. Hence number of bits to represent set field = $14$ bits.

Number of tag bits = $27 - (14+6) = 7$ bits.

Answer (score 0):

To calculate the size of set we know that main memory address is a 2-way set associative cache mapping scheme,hence each set contains 2 blocks.

```
Hence Total no. of sets = Size of cache / Size of set
                        = (2^15/2^1)
                        = 2^14
```

(Which implies that we need 14 bits for the set field)